# Font doesn't load when angular project is deployed in direct admin

Tags: angular, deployment, fonts, directadmin

My Angular Project is running correctly in localhost and all fonts are loaded.
But when I deploy my project on direct admin all the font requests are failed. I have used fontface like this and included assets folder which contains fonts in the angular.json file .

Is there any thing else I should do in direct admin?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-display: block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url('src/assets/fonts/OpenSans.eot');
  url('src/assets/fonts/OpenSans.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('src/assets/fonts/OpenSans.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('src/assets/fonts/OpenSans.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```